# Generation Table from Entities

Tags: java, maven, jpa, eclipselink

I'm new of maven and jpa. I'm develping a modular application using maven. I'm starting to implement it from a model module where i have some annnotated entity bean. Now my trouble is that I want to create the tables from this objects. Is this possible with a maven plugin?

I'm don't have an user interfaces yet, and I can't deploying anything

This is my pom.xml:

```
    <project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>it.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>myparent</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>
        <artifactId>model</artifactId>

  <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

How can I do to generate them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate DDL for JPA 2.0 with EclipseLink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992031/generate-ddl-for-jpa-2-0-with-eclipselink)

Answer (score 0):

If you uses eclipse in your developpement environnement:

This is my proposition :

1- your create a JPA project in eclipse.
2- Your configure the parameters of connexion.(Right click in project ->JPA tools->Genarate table from entites )and continue the steps.

For more details you can use the official documentation of eclipse(JPA tools) : http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jpt.doc.user%2Ftasks021.htm